# Auto next upon clicking image without clicking Next button

Tags: jquery, forms

Hello I wanted my form to be just like this:
https://www.workjustice.com.au/

I'm currently using Wpforms plugin but I think I need costume code for that
anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with the WPForms development/support team?  They'll know how best to customize their forms.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion